# Load an img in a JSP

Tags: html, image, jsp

I'm trying to load an image dynamicaly in a JSP and I'm trying to do something like:

```
<img src="<%= book.img %>">
```

where book.img contains a string (an absolute path). How can I fix the problem?
The error I receive is the following:
 Bad value for attribute src on element img: DOUBLE_WHITESPACE in PATH.

Comment: Which problem? Can you describe it?

Comment: does book.img include the domain and context?

Comment: Why are you using scriptlets and public fields: those are two bad practices, in a single line of code.

Comment: book.img is an absolute path

Comment: @antox I provided you with a pretty generic error, if you need more help, provide your directory structure as well as the value of book.img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`book.img` should contain an absolute url to the image on the server.

So if your images are stored in:

```
Webcontent/resources/images/
```

and you had an image:

```
close-button.png
```

`book.img` should = `/resources/images/close-button.png`

Then in your JSP use JSTL to create the URL:

```
<img src="<c:url value="${book.img}"/>"/>
```

`c:url` will prefix the domain and context to the absolute url.

Another way without JSTL is:

```
 <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}${book.img}"/>
```

Comment: both ways don't work. I noticed that if i replace the image in current folder where my jsp it just works fine, but if I replace the image in another directory, in this case /img/ it doesn't work

Comment: @antox Can you post an example of the url?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a zillion different solutions mostly found in SO where this question is asked 3 or 4 other times.  Many, many answers tell you what to write in your HTML but don't bother to tell you where that means your image file should reside.  The only thing that worked for me was this:

Put your image file directly into your 'WebContent' directory.  Then your HTML in your jsp file is:

```
    <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myImageFileName.png">
```

By extrapolation I'd say that if you put the image file into a subdir such as WebContent/Images then you'd just add that subdir to the src, you can figure out how.  But I didn't test that.